# Serialize an object in django not a model

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, model

I want to serialize an object but this object not a model it just a regular class. How can I do it

```
class Test:
    foo = []
    bar = 1
    a = tt()
class tt
    a = "Test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want this to be objects at all? Looks like it would be better as a nested dict:

```
{
    'foo': [],
    'bar': 1,
    'a': {
        'a': 'Test'
    }
}
```

This of course is directly serializable to JSON via `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize for what purpose? Typically I'm a fan of using [pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) to serialize objects.

```
import pickle
my_obj = Test()
#to save it to file
pickle.dump( my_obj, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )

#to read it from file
my_obj_reloaded = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

Comment: I dont want to save an object into a file .I just want to return a response for my mobile application I successfuly serialize model instances but I dont want to create a db table for return a simple object This object contains List of objects In java I use gson library this library serialize everything. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: If you are returning this data over an API, you probably want to have it as a model. Sure you could use the   https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html json lib to convert it to json and then pass it over in a response, but IMO create a table and let the rest API take care of it. That's what it's there for. You aren't saving any work by not creating a table

Comment: I tried this method but when I try a non Model object to serialize via this method it says ....object is not serializable